# Reading two images as one image Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a collection of images, one group of "left" images and one group of images "right". My task is to read in the "left-01, left-02 etc." and "right-01,right-02 etc." images two at a time (one left and one right image), combine those images to make a new image (Similar to a view from the left eye and right eye combined) then process that image to find non-linear movement using OpenCV. My current implementation reads in one left and one right file, but i cannot think of how to combine those images so they can be processed later.

Here is my method for reading in one left image and one right image:

```
def leftRead():
leftList = []
directoryFiles = glob.glob('left*')
for im in directoryFiles:
    leftList.append(cv2.imread(im, 1))
return leftList

def rightRead():
rightList = []
directoryFiles = glob.glob('right*')
for im in directoryFiles:
    rightList.append(cv2.imread(im, 1))
return rightList
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: declare a resultant image with width equivalent to the sum of left and right image. Copy the images in the resultant image.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a comment but not enough rep. It seems like you are simply trying to create a panorama between the images. Here is a tutorial to do just that. [Panoramic Stitching](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/)